# Instale la dependencia de bluetooth_thermal_printer: ^0.0.6 y al correr el proyecto marca error

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola buenos días estimados.

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Flutter donde tengo que imprimir un ticket por medio de una impresora térmica bluetooth y cuando instalo la dependencia y ejecuto el proyecto me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si comento la dependencia si me deja correr el proyecto.
El error me dice que el complementos solo es compatible con Kotlin Grade 1.5.20 o superior, pero me voy al grade y veo que la version que esta utilizando el proyecto es ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10', lo que hice fue bajarme a la version que me indica para ver si eso lograba solucionar el error, pero el error aun persiste.

Podrían orientarme a como darle solución al error que me marca.

La dependecia que estoy utilizando es la siguiente: [bluetooth_thermal_printer 0.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer/versions/0.0.6)